# Popups not working properly with circle marker

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, ui-leaflet

I'm facing an issue with the circle marker in ui leaflet plugin. When ever a some one clicks on a circle im getting the popup but if I click outside the circle in the map and then try clicking circle again the popup is not coming up.

Can you please suggest what might be the problem? and is there any workaround for this?

Steps to reproduce

1. In map click one circle marker
2. Move the circle marker out of scope of map
3. Then try clicking any other marker the pop up will not appear
4. If I clicked outside the circle and clicked circle again the pop up appears again

Below is the snippet of the code if you need full code please visit this github link

https://github.com/Umamaheswaran1990/learningleaflet

[image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoapp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/ui-leaflet/dist/ui-leaflet.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="LayersSimpleController as vm">
    <leaflet center="center" tiles="tiles" paths="paths" width="50%" height="480px"></leaflet>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("demoapp", ['ui-leaflet']);
app.controller("LayersSimpleController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.map.load', function (event, data) {
        var map = data.leafletObject;
        map.attributionControl.setPrefix(false);
    });

    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.moveend', function (event, data) {
        activate();
    });

    var map = [
        { "lat": 30.7559, "lon": -96.489 },
        { "lat": 41.8887, "lon": -111.769 }];

    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            lat: 39.774769,
            lng: -98.789062,
            zoom: 4,
            minZoom: 4,
            zoomControl: true,
        },
        events: {},
        tiles: {
            url: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            options: {
                subdomains: ['otile1', 'otile2', 'otile3', 'otile4']
            },
            layers: {},
            defaults: {

            }
        }
    });

    activate();

    function activate() {
        $scope.paths = {};
        angular.forEach(map, function (value, key) {
            if (value.lat !== null && value.lon !== null) {
                $scope.paths['circle' + key] = {
                    type: 'circleMarker',
                    className: 'testClass',
                    fillColor: 'DarkSlateGray',
                    color: '#000000',
                    weight: 0,
                    opacity: 1,
                    message: 'This is a test marker',
                    fillOpacity: 0.8,
                    stroke: false,
                    clickable: true,
                    latlngs: [parseFloat(value.lat), parseFloat(value.lon)],
                    radius: 20
                };
            }
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Did you tried in the both browser ? I mean does the problem remains in both of the browsers ?

Comment: @pdfarhad Im able to reproduce the issue in both chrome and forefox surprisingly this works in Edge browser

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding

```
event-broadcast="events"
```

to the leaflet element in index.html, and adding

```
 events: {
          path: {
                 enable: ['click']
                 }
         },
```

to app.js

I'm not sure why this was necessary as the ui-leaflet events example says that all broadcast events are enabled by default. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/events-example